A placing game probability and symmetry
Imagine a simple game: at each moment a true value is drawn from some distribution with the CDF $F_\mu$ which is centered around $\mu$, and your decision should be putting the lower $l$ and upper $u$ bounds for this value according to the following payoff:

if the drawn value is below $l$ you get $\mu - l$
if the drawn value is above $u$ you get $u - \mu$
otherwise you get nothing

Under these conditions it is easy to show that optimal $l, u$ should be equidistant from $\mu$, i.e. $\mu = (l + u)/2$.
Consider now the case where $\mu$ itself is first drawn from some distribution $G_{\nu}$ which is centered around $\nu$, whereas payoffs stay the same. I was wondering whether optimal $l, u$ must also be equidistant in this case or is there a counterexample. I've tried to prove the claim first, but I'm now lost in conditional expectation expressions when trying to apply symmetry argument: if $l$ satisfies the optimality condition for the lower bound than $2\nu - l$ satisfies the one for the upper bound. These optimality conditions for the general case I've obtained as:
$$
\begin{align}
u - \hat{\mu}(u) &= \frac{\Bbb E_\mu[1 - F(u|\mu)]}{\Bbb E_\mu f(u|\mu)}
\\
\\
\hat{\mu}(l) - l &= \frac{\Bbb E_\mu F(l|\mu)}{\Bbb E_\mu f(l|\mu)}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\hat{\mu}(x) = \frac{\Bbb E_\mu[\mu f(x|\mu)]}{\Bbb E_\mu f(x|\mu)}.
$$
Also here $F, f$ are CDF and PDF given $\mu$ and $\Bbb E_\mu$ is just integral with respect to the distribution $G_\nu$. The conditions above I've obtained simply by taking the payoff derivative to be $0$.
Any help is appreciated.

I'm unclear about the order in which things are happening in this game. Is mu drawn before or after l and u are picked?

After. $u$ and $l$ is something for you to pick optimally, $\mu$ is drawn after, and then the value is drawn according to $F_\mu$

By "centred around $x$" I assume you mean "symmetric with median $x$".
Since $l$ and $u$ are chosen right at the beginning, this reduces to the original game with some mixture distribution $H_\nu$ centred on $\nu$. So the optimal $l$, $u$ would be equidistant from $\nu$.
Using plenty of abuses of notation, you effectively have $H_\nu=\int F_\mu dG_\nu(\mu)$.
EDIT: OP clarified a detail in the comments that the payoffs are still calculated using the now-random $\mu$. Then let's argue more generally. WLOG let $\nu=0$, so we'll be picking $u\geq0$ and $l\leq0$. Let's use the fact that the total payoff can be decomposed into a $u$-contribution and a $l$-contribution.
Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be the expected payoff function for $u$, i.e.
$$f(u) = \mathbb E[(u-\mu)^+ \cdot 1_{\{ X + \mu > u \}}]$$
where $X$ has distribution $F_0$ and is independent of $\mu$.
Then $-\mu$ has the same distribution as $\mu$, and $-X$ has the same distribution as $X$, so it's possible to show that the expected payoff function for $l$ is
$$\mathbb E[(\mu-l)^+ \cdot 1_{\{ X + \mu < l \}}] = f(-l).$$
Thus a choice of $l$ maximises its expected payoff if and only if it is the negative of a choice of $u$ that maximises its expected payoff.

I thought of that as well, but upper and lower bound are compared not to the $\nu$ but $\mu$ which is random now, and I’m not sure whether the problem is linear enough to make the jump from the value to its mean. Intuitively I agree, but I think the formal derivation is needed

Thanks for that clarification - it's worth making that super clear in your question. I've edited my answer with a different approach that should work even in this case.
